# ANGULAR: ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, filtering

I am trying to filter my array by using modula on the id by clicking multiple buttons. I tried using pipe but i was recommended using this since using pipe didn't work for me. I don't know what to do, i see many video's online but they get too complicated or i always get some error that they don't have. Or am i just going in the wrong direction for a simple onclick filter. I am quite a beginner to angular
[image: the error]

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { StreamService } from '../stream.service';
import { Stream } from '../stream';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-discover',
  templateUrl: './discover.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./discover.component.scss']
})
export class DiscoverComponent implements OnInit {
  streams!: Stream[];
  
  constructor(private streamService: StreamService) { 
    
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getStreams();
  }

  getStreams(){
    this.streamService.getStream().subscribe((data =>{
      this.streams = data;
      console.log(this.streams);
    }))
  }

  sortBack(){
    this.streams.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
  }


  filterIsUneven(){
    this.streams.filter(stream => stream.id % 3)
    console.log(this.filterIsUneven());
  };
  
  

}
```

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Stream } from './stream';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs';
 
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StreamService{

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getStream():Observable<Stream[]>{
  return this.http.get<Stream[]>("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1/photos");
  }

getLiveStream(id:number):Observable<Stream[]> {
  const url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1/photos?id=${id}`;
  return this.http.get<Stream[]>(url);
  }
}
```

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="buttons">
    <button (click) = "filterIsUneven()"> Games </button>
    <button> Music </button>
    <button> Esports </button>
    <button> IRL </button>
    <button>Back</button>
  </div>

  <div class="streams" *ngFor="let stream of streams">
    <h3>{{stream.id}}</h3>
    <h3>{{stream.title}}</h3>
    <img src="{{stream.thumbnailUrl}}">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: endless loop in ```filterIsUneven``` function.

Comment: yes, how do i stop that, i tried using a if function but that didn't work either, or did i just write a wrong if function.

Comment: `if` is not a "function" but a condition. And nobody will know, if you "did just write a wrong if" if you don't show it. But probably you did, because otherwise the recursion would have stopped.

Comment: Remove the console.log.

Comment: @derpirscher you are right , this is the if condition i used  ``` if (this.streams.filter(stream => stream.id % 3)) {
      return;"```` but i feel its wrong, its confusing to how to mix it with the .filter();

Comment: `if (this.streams.filter(...))` will ALWAYS return a truthy and thus, the body will be executed because even if applied on an empty array, it will return an empty array. No offense, but you shouldn't just throw in random pieces of code and hope for the best, but learn the basics of programming and read the docs of the functions you are using. What do you expect from `console.log(this.filterIsUneven()` anyways? Your function does not have a return value, so what should `console.log` log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

console.log() in filterIsUneven is causing endless recursion. Remove console log and it should be fine.